# How to speed up the UI

Tags: angular

I am working with an angular 6 project. I've a page with 7 tabs and getting thoses data from a single service call. For the easy manipulation of these tab contents I've created 7 components and rendert it's from the parent. These 7 tabs contains a huge amount of data and not able to appy the pagination because of the json complexity. It's getting so slow to perform the actions like focus, click, change...etc. I've heard and tried with the ' ***changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush***' then it's become little faster but some functionalities initiates from the parent tab not reflecting those child components. Please help me to fix the same.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Fetch data of all 7 tabs on click on that tab

Comment: the *json complexity* is a problem in your design, not in Angular. It's not a problem related to code and we hardly can help you. By the way, when handling many data, the best thing to do is using virtual scrolling

Comment: @Dhawal actually the server side api is proving it as like. I don't think they will change the logic. That's why I am struggling.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Cristian Traìna, I think you have to try with virtual scrolling.

Comment: Angular can actually handle lots of data and huge masks if you do change detection on push right. But you have to put a container component around you tab components in order to prevent change detection to go on all the tabs on every change - as written in my updated answer. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/github/thoughtram/angular2-change-detection-demos) is a demo how change detection works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush before you use it - it can have some pitfalls. When using changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush angular stops tracking all of your changes. From now on, angular only detects changes when a event occurs, the input data has changed or you trigger change detection. Here is an explanation: [A Comprehensive Guide to angular change detection strategy](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4) and here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/github/thoughtram/angular2-change-detection-demos)

For all other changes (and that includes changes you make in a event handler as they occur after the actual event), you have to trigger change detection manually using ChangeDetectorRef:

```
constructor(cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

changeYourModel() {
  // do some stuff
  this.cdRef.markForCheck();
}
```

The advantage of changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush is, that you define the moment when a change detection is triggered. Without changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush it is possible that angular does changeDetection several times and in vain because the next change is just about to happen. The other thing with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush is that it encapsulates changes as not the whole mask is updated / detected on every single change.

You can use that by dividing your component into many smaller components to encapsulate the changes made to that one component. As you can see in the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/github/thoughtram/angular2-change-detection-demos), the change detection detects changes that are made on the same tree level. Therefore dividing your Component into 7 tab component is not enough. Make a logic Component and put it into a (on push) tab-container Component in order to prevent changes to be spread to other components.

Further on, look at the performance tab in Chrome dev tools and run some performance tests to see what is actually taking a lot of time. Also have a look at the network tabs and see if every call is needed or if some things can be loaded one and be cached.

Comment: While using "ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush" it's not binding the DOM properly. So I just dropped that plan and trying to clean the code.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is for material design tabs but you could use same for your tabs.
By declaring the body in a ng-template it would be loaded lazily, so when user click on this tab.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      The First Content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      The Second Content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```